# How to test if an iframe has access to top without throwing "Unsafe JavaScript attempt..." errors?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe

I am working on a widget, and its behavior will be slightly different depending on whether it renders in an iframe that has access to top vs. not.

I need a good way to test for whether the frame has access to top or not. I can do this with a simple try/catch block, the problem is that Chrome always seems to show the "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL" error in the console, even when the call is wrapped in a try/catch. See example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/XbS9J/

```
try {
    var ___loc = top.location.toString();
    console.log('top is accessible');
} catch (e) {
    console.log('top is not accessible');
}
```

Is there any way to test for access to top from an iframe and NOT have chrome throw an error during the process when there is no access to top? This seems fine in other browsers, but chrome is being annoying.